# How to use TTSE Method instead of EOS in CoolProp Version 6.4.3 in Python

Tags: python

I want to use the TTSE Method for the PropsSI Function instead of EOS. I tried out as said by the documentation but it doesn't work.

```
import CoolProp

import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP

CP.enable_TTSE_LUT("Propane")

CP.PropsSI("D", "P", 101.325, "Q", 0, "Propane")
```

But he just tells me, that CP does not have the attribute "enable_TTSE_LUT"

I use Python Version 3.10 and my CoolProp Version is 6.4.3

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word **traceback**. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.